# How to display data instead of recently viewed products are not there

Tags: products-view, ce-1.9.0.1

When recently viewed products are not there it shows blank space, I want to display some text or html on that blank space and after visited products it will display recently viewed products.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Goto `app\design\frontend\<namespace>\<theme>\template\reports\product_viewed.phtml`

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Recently Viewed Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ol id="recently-viewed-items">
        <?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName() , 'name') ?></a></p>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Check the condition here

```
<?php if(count($_products) > 0): ?>
    <ol id="recently-viewed-items">
        <?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName() , 'name') ?></a></p>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
<?php else: ?>
    <div><span><?php echo $this->__('your message')?>;?></span></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

**FYI:** if you dont have file get it from the base folder with same folder structure

Comment: @swash enable the path hint and put the condition in that view file

Comment: It's not working,below is my code....<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Recently Viewed') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content custom-content">
    <?php if(count($_products)): ?><ol id="recently-viewed-items">
         <?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?><li class="item">

Comment: <p><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item,true); ?></p>
            </li> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
        <?php else: ?>
     <div><span><?php echo $this->__('your message')?>;?></span></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?><?php endif; ?>

Comment: change the condition as `if(count($_product)>0)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite function `_toHtml()` of Block class `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed`

```
protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->getCount()) {
            return ''; // Here you can return your custom text
        }
        $this->setRecentlyViewedProducts($this->getItemsCollection());
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
```

It is not advisable t make direct changes in core files, create your custom module rewrite this block.